# How to insert csv file content into html file within pre tag using shell script

Tags: html, shell, csv

I need to insert csv file (file.csv) content such as:

```
col1, col2, ...coln
1,2,3
4,5,6
.
.
100,101,102
```

Into an html file (file.html) within the `<pre>  </pre>` tags.

The desire result in file.html:

```
<html>
.
.
<pre>
col1, col2, ...coln
1,2,3
4,5,6
.
.
100,101,102
</pre>
.
.
</html>
```

I know it can be acomplished using `sed` but don't know the specifics.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your result the actual result you want? or just a snippet? Is there exactly one `<pre>`?

Comment: @NickSlash it is just an snippet, in this case there is just one <pre>

Comment: Please provide a well-formed sample HTML input file.

Comment: Your best bet is using some HTML-aware preprocessor, static page generator or in-server template engine, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
gawk -i inplace '/<pre[^>]*>/{printf $0; while(getline line<"file.csv"){print line};next}1' file.html &&
```